# Error reading a local html file with urllib3

Tags: python, urllib3

I am trying to read a previous downloaded html file with urllib3.

I have tried with:

```
import urllib3

url = 'file:///test.html/' 
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
request = http.request('GET',url)

print(request.data)
```

but I got this:

`urllib3.exceptions.LocationValueError: No host specified.`

It is not supposed that there should be a 'host' because I already downloaded the file and it is on my local file system.

I have tried changing the syntax of the url but it has not worked. What should be the correct syntax of the url?

Comment: I guess you need a server for getting a response to your http request. If you have the html file in your local, why don't you just read it like a local file?

Comment: Do you mean as a 'localhost', @samik ?

Comment: Yes, if you run a http server on your local machine, you should be able to access the file over http using host `localhost`.

Comment: @Samik, yes, your answer is right as a shortcut for me. I'm trying to avoid to deploy an HTTP server to solve this issue. But you make me realize that PoolManager must be trying to read over HTTP no with other protocols. If I want to read it as a file probably I need another approach. Thanks!